# Table doesn't display correctly when narrow (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I'm having some grief with tables I'm trying to set up in WordPress. [Have a look here](http://www.theoldmilkingparlourcornwall.co.uk/booking/q1-2015/) - the page looks OK when at a normal desktop width (say 1000px), but when you narrow it down below about 750px, the tables start repeating information for no apparent reason. I've flicked through my CSS and through my tables themselves and can't seem to find any immediate reason why. This is only a problem for when mobile users try to view the page.

One of the tables is as follows.

```
<table style="height: 25px;" border="1" width="673" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>WEEK</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>PRICE</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>AVAILABLE</strong></em></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="height: 120px;" border="1" width="673" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong> 3rd Jan to 10th Jan</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>£359</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>Available </strong></em></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>10th Jan to 17th Jan</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>£359</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong> <strong><em>Available </em></strong></strong></em></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>17th Jan to 24th Jan</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>£359</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong> <strong><em>Available </em></strong></strong></em></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>24th Jan to 31st Jan</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>£359</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><em><strong> <span style="color: #000000;"><strong><em>Available </em></strong></span></strong></em></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><b><i>31st Jan to 7th Feb</i></b></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong>£359</strong></em></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="bottom" width="206"><em><strong> <span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><em>BOOKED</em></strong></span></strong></em></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas why this might be doing this?

Comment: It's caused by `responsive-tables.js`, function `splitTable`, 10th line of this file: `if ((jQuery(window).width() < 767) && !switched ){...`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your CSS, but there will be a breakpoint set for 785px that displays elements with class 'pinned', making the duplicate table entries appear.

try:

```
@media all max-width: 785px {
  .pinned {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Better is find a piece of code which double table and fix that, than just hide this code in CSS.